# inclusive memory address of function

Tags: memory

Maybe a simple question but I have a function that states:

The start address (char* beg) is inclusive, whilst the end address (char* end) is exclusive.

So, lets say I have an array like

```
double A[N][N];
```

How do I state the inclusive start and exclusive end, like this?

Start

```
(char*)A
```

End

```
(char*)&A[N][N]
```

or should I write the end like this.

```
(char*)&A[N-1][N-1]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is quite unusual to pass a 2D array of doubles with char* bounds. Are you sure that your function can handle such a content ?

Comment: I am trying to pass just the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start sounds good.
End: 
`((char*)A) + sizeof(A)`

Comment: But doesn't the end of the array A[N][N] have the same memory address as what you have written?

Comment: The end of the array ends just before this address, this address is one byte after the array, was not that what you were looking for ?

Comment: If that was exclusive means :)  Is it one before or one after.  So, that one last byte will contain data from the array too?

Comment: Do that with a single char:
"char a;". The start will be &a. The end will be (&a + sizeof(char)). Here end is the end of the data, exclusive, meaning the data pointed by it is not part of the data. For an array it's exactly the same.

Comment: I guess it makes no difference in terms of syntax if I make an array on the heap?